# Why am I getting a blank space at right side of a page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this blank white space at the right side of the browser. I don't know what is causing this. I am using twitter bootstrap.

[Here's the site](http://8tracksdownloader.tk)

If overflow:hidden is added, then the scroll bars disappears. Please help me get this resolved.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: You need to provide more details that just a link.  Is this a cross browser issue?  What does the page source look like?  Have you validated the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div with the id loader contains a div with the classes span, 5 and offset5. Remove the offset5 class and set css of the img inside it to `margin: 0 auto; display: block;`

Comment: How I found this was by using Chromes Developer Tools and one by one deleting the div's until I found the culprit. Read up about about the Dev Tools, will save you a whole lot of bother. Firefox and Safari have similar tools as well, as does IE - but like the rest of its browser, are slightly lacking.